# Overlap plots in R - from zoo package

Tags: r, plot, overlap, zoo

Using the following code:

```
library("ggplot2")
require(zoo)   

args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
input <- read.csv(args[1], header=F, col.names=c("POS","ATT"))
id <- args[2]

prot_len <- nrow(input)
manual <- prot_len/100 # 4.3

att_name <- "Entropy" 

att_zoo <- zoo(input$ATT)
att_avg <- rollapply(att_zoo, width = manual, by = manual, FUN = mean, align = "left")

autoplot(att_avg, col="att1") + labs(x = "Positions", y = att_name, title="")
```

With data:

```
> str(input)
'data.frame':   431 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ POS: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ ATT: num  0.652 0.733 0.815 1.079 0.885 ...
```

I do:
[image]
I would like to upload `input2` which has different lenght (therefore, different x-axis) and overlap the 2 curves in the same plot (I mean overlap because I want the two curves in the same plot size, so I will "ignore" the overlapped axis labels and tittles), I would like to compare the shape, regardles the lenght of input.

First I've tried by generating toy `input2` changing `manual` value, so that I have `att_avg2` in which `manual` equals e.g. 7. In between original `autoplot` and new `autoplot`-2 I add `par(new=TRUE)`, but this is not my expected output. Any hint on how doing this? Maybe it's better to save `att_avg` from zoo series to data.frame and not use `autoplot`? Thanks

UPDATE, response to G. Grothendieck:

If I do:

```
[...]
att_zoo <- zoo(input$ATT)
att_avg <- rollapply(att_zoo, width = manual, by = manual, FUN = mean, align = "left") #manual=4.3
att_avg2 <- rollapply(att_zoo, width = 7, by = 7, FUN = mean, align = "left")

autoplot(cbind(att_avg, att_avg2), facet=NULL) +
  labs(x = "Positions", y = att_name, title="")
```

I get 
[image]
and a warning message:
`Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_path).`

Answer (score 1):

`par` is used with classic graphics, not for ggplot2.  If you have two zoo series just `cbind` or `merge` the series together and `autoplot` them using `facet=NULL`:

```
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)

z1 <- zoo(1:3) # length 3
z2 <- zoo(5:1) # length 5

autoplot(cbind(z1, z2), facet = NULL)
```

**Note:** The question omitted `input2` so there could be some additional considerations from aspects not shown.

[image]

Comment: Hi, G. Grothendieck, thanks for your reply. I applied your suggestion but I got an unexpected plot, see in update.

Comment: You likely have NAs in the cbind'ed zoo object.   Its for reasons like this that you should provide complete self-contained examples that include the inputs.  Try `autoplot(na.approx(cbind(z1, z2)), facet = NULL)`

Comment: Thank you, that fix the plot. The problem is that the real data will have different lengths and different data points, that's why I said that I wanted to overlap the plots -as if they were transparent slides-, not trying to include the different curves into the same plot, I don't want R try to fit the 2 curves into the same x-axis. Is that possible?